# AJAX форма дублирует письма

Tags: ajax, формы, ajax-load

AJAX Форма на сайте шлет 2 письма - одно пустое, другое - как надо.
Почему дублируется еще и пустое ?

Код формы:

```
<div class="bl-form" id="ggs_form">
<p class="success_phraze"></p>
<div class="success_delete">
<div class="heading" style="text-align: center;">Закажите мастера он-лайн.</div>
<div class="promotion" style="text-align: center;">Летняя <strong>акция</strong> до <span class="time_action">16</span> августа. Скидка <strong>20%</strong></div>
<div class="text" style="text-align: center;">Для консультации мастера обращайтесь по нашему многоканальному номеру <strong><a class="phone mgo-number-13606" href="tel:+78125653523">8 (812) 565-35-23</a></strong></div>
<div class="text" style="text-align: center;">или заполните эту форму и мы Вам сразу перезвоним.</div>
</div>

<form action="/wp-content/themes/cj27965/php/send.php" method="post"><label>Номер телефона *</label>
<input class="input phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Формат: 81234567890" required />
<label>Имя</label>
<input class="input" name="name" type="text" required />
<input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Оформить заявку" />
<div class="form-policy">Нажимая на кнопку «Оформить заявку», вы подтверждаете своё совершеннолетие и соглашаетесь на обработку персональных данных в соответствии с <a href="/policy/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">условиями</a>.</div>
</form></div>
```

Код AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      $('#ggs_form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $('#ggs_form form');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-content/themes/cj27965/php/send1.php",
            data: $form.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            $('#ggs_form .success_delete').fadeOut(150);
            $('#ggs_form input[type="text"]').val('');
            $('#ggs_form .success_phraze').load('/wp-content/themes/cj27965/php/send1.php');
            console.log('success');
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log('fail');
        });
        e.preventDefault(); 
      });
    });
</script>
```

Код Скрипта отправки:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
// $comment = $_POST['comment'];

if ( $name != '' ) { $subject = '[С сайта GGS] Клиент! - '.$name; }

$message = '';

if ( $name != '' ) { $message .= 'Имя ('.$name.') '; }
if ( $phone != '' ) { $message .= 'Телефон ('.$phone.') '; }
if ( $mail != '' ) { $message .= 'E-mail ('.$mail.')'; }
if ( $city != '' ) { $message .= 'Город ('.$city.')'; }
// if ( $comment != '' ) { $message .= 'Комментарий ('.$comment.')'; }

$mail = 'xxx';
mail($mail, $subject, $message, '');

$mail = 'yyy';
mail($mail, $subject, $message, '');

echo "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <div class='heading'>Спасибо за ваше обращение!</div>
    <div class='text'>Спасибо за заявку. Мы вам перезвоним.</div>
";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#ggs_form').submit(function(e) {
            var $form = $('#ggs_form form');
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-content/themes/cj27965/php/send1.php",
            data: $form.serialize()
        }).done(function(resp) {
            $('#ggs_form .success_delete').fadeOut(150);
            $('#ggs_form input[type="text"]').val('');
            $('#ggs_form .success_phraze').html(resp);
            console.log('success');
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log('fail');
        });
        e.preventDefault(); 
        });
    });
</script>
```